# Unexpected 1 pixel margin in Edge browser

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I am having an unexpected 1px margin under a div residing in a fixed container. This issue only occurs in Edge (possibly in IE as well). After some testing, I was able to reproduce the bug with a bare bones example.

This picture, which you can reproduce running the snippet below, is composed of 3 square divs inside a fixed div. Firefox

[image]

In Edge, you can "fix" this issue by either disabling the property `top: 50%` in the container div, or by disabling `border-*-right-radius: 6px` in the divs inside it. Naturally, this isn't a fix, because I need both these properties to effectively implement this design.

How can I fix this? I tried adding borders the same color as the background, but the background is not opaque.

Edit: If you can't see it right away in IE/Edge, try to select the container `div` and slowly increase the value of the `top` property. In IE11, changing it from 5% to 6% already made the problem obvious again.

```css
.box {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.box:hover {
  background-color: rgba(50,50,100,0.15);
}
.box:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.box:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.main {
  width: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not reproducible in IE11; looks like it's Edge-only.

Comment: Not reproducing in FF either. You can however use a before or after element like .box:after{} and position absolute something on top of that container.

Comment: Thanks for testing, but I just tested it myself and IE has it as well, but slightly less noticeable. Check my update.

Comment: Firefox and Chrome are fine, no matter how hard I try to break it.

Comment: Did you try removing: «line-height: 70px;»?

Comment: I reproduced this in IE 11. This is because of border-radius. Remove it and it will be fixed. http://jsfiddle.net/gtf0fa8n/

Comment: I already mentioned that in my question. I can't just remove a design feature. It doesn't fix this issue, just hides it until next time.

Comment: Look like a rendering issue so doubt you will be able to fix it. [Check this](https://jsfiddle.net/n5169o7r/) and resize the display panel, you will see it flicker between the 2 edges. It also sometimes doesn't show the line at all (as desired) and to be honest, isn't it what we expect Edge to do? as in, not work well

Comment: Yup, it is what we've come to expect. I noticed that flickering as well. Problem is that if you move or resize the window, it will probably snap one of the two edges again. I'll try a different approach then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use border on parent div: http://jsfiddle.net/gtf0fa8n/1/

Border radius on parent does not brake inner divs rendering in IE

```
.main {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-left: 0;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
}
.box:hover {
    background-color: rgba(50,50,100,0.15);
}
```

Comment: Can you put the code inline instead of a fiddle please? Better for the site

Comment: Then look at how the hover effect breaks it! I think the real solution is to wait for an updated version of Edge... in about 5 years

Comment: @musefan Edge is updated with rolling updates, just like Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @TylerH people get easily fooled but big version numbers. MS simply follows better versioning practices.

Comment: For design reasons I'm not going to apply the border-radius to the container, but I will apply the transparent background instead. which works just fine.

Comment: @ecc the switch from Microsoft Internet Explorer to Microsoft Edge is more than a "big version number" change. It's an entirely new browser, new name, new rendering engine, new roadmap and development philosophy. It's important that people understand this so that they don't continue to harbor outdated and harmful prejudices toward Edge.

Answer (score 2):

Just give boxshadow of 1px with same color on bottom.

```
box-shadow: #2a2e37 0px 1px 0px;
```

Comment: Ran into this issue with my footer. Tried a lot and nothing was working. Thanks for this brilliant workaround.